# D3: Accessing Objects in Bound array using variables

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to animate monthly data across a map. I've stored each month's data all together within an array, and when I try to bind the data like so with: `.data(data.January)` it will work. However, when using the variable tracking the current month selected with `.data(data.monthName)` it returns a `TypeError` in the console and does not render the rest of the application.

My guess is that I'm accessing the key values incorrectly, and that d3 has a unique way of handling that.

Below is the function that doesn't work. (`update()` is fired when the slider controls change months.)

```js
d3.json("data/avg_revisit.json", function(data) {
color.domain([20, 0]);
  function update() {
        var monthName = getMonthName(currentMonth);
        colored_bars.selectAll("rect")
          .data(data.monthName)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
            .attr("width", getLandWidth())
            .attr("class", "bars")
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return projection([0, d.latitude - 0.5])[1] - projection([0, d.latitude])[1];
            })
            .attr("opacity", 0.6)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              //Get data value
              var value = d.average_revisit;

              if (value) {
                      //If value exists…
                      return color(value);
              } else {
                      //If value is undefined…
                      return "#ccc";
              }
             })
             //Define position of each rectangle by it's latitude from the data
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + projection([-180, d.latitude]) + ")"
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data[monthName]` instead of `data.monthName`. If you are using a variable to access the key of an object you must use `object[string variable]`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I knew something small was tripping me up. Thanks so much.

Comment: It also works for invalid names. For example, if you have a key named "1st", you can't write `data.1st`, but you can write `data["1st"]`.